# 'the' before university names

Tags: definite-articles

Guess I will multiply threads, but sorry, I'm still confused:

*at Jan Kazimierz University in Lwow*

or

*at **the** Jan Kazimierz University in Lwow*

I've found the second one more common, though I feel the first one is more appropriate because the university is named after a person (Polish King Jan Kazimierz)? I mean, you don't say *at **the** Stanford University*, do you?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter for individual institutions to decide what they are called? I'd look at their own literature and follow whichever style they adopted, if you wish to be scrupulously correct. if they were not consistent then you don't need to be. However, I'd be wary of extrapolating to English the naming conventions of Polish Universities at the beginning of the last century.

Comment: Yes, it is up to the institution to decide.  The prime example in the USA  is a certain uni  which most folks just call "Ohio State," but alums proudly refer to as "**The** Ohio State University"

Comment: Thank you both. The trouble is that it's a historical name. Wikipedia goes for the first option (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lviv_University#Jan_Kazimierz_University_.281919.E2.80.9339.29), but from google I get a lot more hits for the second one :-/

Comment: I think the problem with this question is that it is asking what the English language style is for the type of university name that is more common in continental Europe (especially Germany,  but here Poland) — one with the name of an individual (or other adjective) as well as a place. First, we don't talk about these universities very much (I'd never heard of the one at Lwow and woud use "at" or "of" rather than "in"), and those of us that do would probably translate. The only generalization (should be in answer) I would make is adjectives like "Free". In English they need an article.

Comment: This is perhaps one of the most frequently asked questions here, from *[Is there a rule of thumb when to use “the” in front of universities?](/q/207626)* to *[When is there a “the” at the beginning of a university's name?](/q/12965)* Please also see *[Use of definite article before phrases like Heathrow Airport, Hyde Park, Waterloo Station, Edgware Road and Parliament Square](/q/34704)* and *[Why there is “the” before some names but not others](/q/59271)*

Answer (score 0):

The guideline is the same as for business names. If the name contains *of*, then you should use *the* before. Hence, [The University of Arizona](http://www.arizona.edu/about) but [Arizona State University](https://www.asu.edu/?feature=aboutasu/).

Comment: A citation from a style book would be helpful

Comment: The example given by the OP  is more complex than just a place name, but also includes the name of a person in a style more common in Germany and other parts continental Europe. So your rule of thumb can't really apply.